# How to add existing WordPress menu item links to custom designed new header?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I designed a custom header for my website. The website is not fully designed, so I kept the old theme and just changed front-page.php with new-header.php and new-footer.php include.

I linked existing menu items in new-header.php like below,

```
<li class="">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us/">About Us</a>
</li>
```

When I connect blog,

```
<li class="">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/blog/">About Us</a>
</li>
```

it's working. (it's a different folder outside wp-content)

but when I connect other pages like about us / contact us, it's showing critical error.
Has anyone experienced this kind of issue? please let me know...

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details for anyone to help you yet.  What's the error? How are you including your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points needs to cross check

1. Hope you have defined new header like

   get_header('new');

Please refer to for more details
https://www.webascender.com/blog/how-to-create-multiple-headers-footers-in-wordpress/

2. Resave your permalinks.